# How i can make a sorted table using react-semantic-ui and functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to make [this table sortable](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#variations-sortable) but in the example are using class component and i have a functional component.

I try to make this way:

```
    const WorkOutList = props => {

    const handleSort = (clickedColumn) => () => {

        const [column, data, direction] = useState(0);

        if (column !== clickedColumn) {
          this.setState({
            column: clickedColumn,
            data: _.sortBy(data, [clickedColumn]),
            direction: 'ascending',
          })

          return
        }

        this.setState({
          data: data.reverse(),
          direction: direction === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending',
        })
    }

    const renderRows = () => {
        const list = props.list || []
        return list.map(workout => (

            <Table.Row key={workout.id}>
                <Table.Cell>{workout.tempoGasto}h</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{workout.tipoTarefa}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{workout.data}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                    <Button
                    animated='vertical'
                    onClick={() => props.removeWorkout(workout)}
                    >
                        <Button.Content hidden>Deletar</Button.Content>
                        <Button.Content visible>
                            <Icon name='trash' />
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
        ))
    }

    return (
        <Table sortable celled fixed>
            <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                    <Table.HeaderCell
                     sorted={props.column === 'tempoGasto' ? direction : null}
                     onClick={handleSort('tempoGasto')}
                    >
                        Tempo
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell
                     sorted={props.column === 'tipoTarefa' ? direction : null}
                     onClick={handleSort('tipoTarefa')}
                    >
                        Tipo
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell
                     sorted={props.column === 'data' ? direction : null}
                     onClick={handleSort('data')}
                    >
                        Data
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>
                        Ações
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                </Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>

            <Table.Body>
                {renderRows()}
            </Table.Body>
        </Table>
    )
}
```

I'm using react and redux, but i'm receiving:

> Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

The full code is in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4ZNcFSBM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have used `useState` hook inside of a function.

```
 const [column, data, direction] = useState(0);
```

You need to write this at your component level outside of any function.

Another issue is, you have incorrect definition of `useState`. `useState` give you pair of the value and it's setter function.

```
const [data, setData]  = useState(0)
```

Now you can change value of data using `setData` setter function,

```
setData(1)
```

Read more about `useState` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

---

You can actually store object in state,

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
                            column: "",
                            data: "",
                            direction: "",
                        })
```

And use `setData` setter function for state change,

```
setData(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     column: clickedColumn,
     data: _.sortBy(prevState.data, [clickedColumn]),
     direction: 'ascending',
  })
)
```

[Check this for how to use useState](https://daveceddia.com/usestate-hook-examples/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198459/discussion-on-answer-by-ravibagul91-how-i-can-make-a-sorted-table-using-react-se).